# Change column data type from text to array by splitting on delimiter

Tags: postgresql, types, alter-table

I need to change column data type. It contains text in form `"part1 part2 part3"`.

I want its contents to be represented as an array (`["part1", "part2", "part3"]`).

What is the easiest way to do that? Do I need to write a program or is it possible to do using only SQL?

I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to select that as an array:

```
select string_to_array(your_column, ' ')
from your_table;
```

If you permanently want to change the data type to e.g `text[]` use this:

```
alter table your_table 
      alter your_column type text[] using string_to_array(your_column, ' ');
```

Comment: I get following error:
function string_to_array(text[], unknown) does not exist